# Conflict merging fork on `package.json` on name/version

Tags: git, npm, gitlab, package.json, package-lock.json

## TL;DR :

I want to avoid conflicts each time I'm merging my bumped base project **package.version** in the forked one containing a different **package.name**.

## Issue :

### Context

I maintain two git repos, named here `base` and `fork`, each contains a shared `package.json` and the `package-lock.json` accordingly. They got a propert `name` to `base` and `base_fork` respectively, the second has been updated since the first commit after forking. Each lives in gitlab context and the second is created with the fork option of gitlab.

### Workflow

A version bump happen in `base`, I update the lockfile with an `npm i` then push to `base` master branch. I'm starting a merge request with gitlab from `base` master to `fork` master. This one fail due to conflict that I need to resolve manually in `package.json` and `package-lock.json` :

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "name": "fork",
  "version": "1.0.0",
=======
  "name": "base",
  "version": "1.0.1"
>>>>>>> xxxxxxxx
```

So, I'm taking `name` from HEAD and `version` from commit xxxxxxxx. And push to resolve conflict.

### Problem

The conflict appear due to `name` change + `version` change. Technically, git detect a conflict, I can understand why, but it's boring me ^^ . So, I moved away the version line from `package.json` that's fixing the problem for this file but the `package-lock.json` is a solid I can't manage like that.

### So!

I think the problem can be reproduce with a branching system since it's just a merging business but this case happen clearly in a fork context with this kind of change. I understand my problem come from the conflict detection I could solve but there is one file I can't manage.

To be clear a last time about what I'm waiting for here :

A way to avoid conflict during merge from `base` to `fork` on specific declared lines. In this case the lines 2~3 of `package-lock.json`.

Any ways are welcome :)

EDIT:

Following @inigo solution, I'm investigate [custom merge driver solutions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) taking [praqma sample](https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver) as model.

Comment: Please update this question with details per my comment below. It appears you want something that is logically unreasonable. If not, explain. Flagging as needing clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a custom merge driver with the `merge=ours` strategy in `.gitattributes`:

```
package-lock.json merge=ours
```

Enable this strategy with:

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

You could do the same for `package.json` and discard the workaround you're using now.

Comment: Sounds great ! I'll try that but I prefer keep conflicts that could happen on package.json if dependencies differ ^^

Comment: IMO, that's not solving my issue but moving it. I prefer to keep conflicts happens on the other lines. Not marking the whole package-lock.json as "merge-ours". Assuming I have a new dependency in "fork" my conflict, this solution will result to a painful bug detection from package-lock.

Comment: The point is I'm using `npm ci` which is using only the lock file. In another hand, I don't know if there is an npm way to solve it, I'm not lock with the git one. And as far I know, there is commands for `git rebase` allowing to select specific lines for operations. Your solution bring me to another complex merge drivers calling shell file that could be fit my case. Still WIP.

Comment: I can't assume marking "solve" if solution pop another issues relative to the problem. I prefer this way to say "That's impossible" and keep the conflicts. Sounds like more reasonable.